# Server Error in '\' Application "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection parameter name:index

Tags: c#, sharepoint

"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection parameter name:index. this is a screenshot:
[This is the bug from my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gavs.jpg) when I will choose a document to be printed, the application will print other documents at random. Please need your help master :(
This is my code:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        trackingDataContext dc = new trackingDataContext(MyClass.conn);
        if (e.CommandName == "Print")
        {
            int row = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()) + (GridView1.PageIndex * GridView1.PageSize);
            GridViewRow gr = GridView1.Rows[row];
            string ID = gr.Cells[0].Text;
            string jenis_dokumen = gr.Cells[2].Text;
            string nopek = gr.Cells[4].Text;
            string rdl = "";
            var td = (from t in dc.tracking_dokumens where t.id == Convert.ToInt16(ID) select t).SingleOrDefault();
            var area = (from a in dc.field_lists where a.id == td.field_id select a).SingleOrDefault();
            if (area.field_name == "Kantor Pusat Jakarta")
            {
                if (jenis_dokumen == "SPD")
                {
                    rdl = "deklarasi.rdl";
                }
                else if (jenis_dokumen == "Panjar Dinas")
                {
                    rdl = "panjar_dinas.rdl";
                }
                else if (jenis_dokumen == "Pengajuan Panjar Kerja")
                {
                    rdl = "panjar_kerja.rdl";
                }
                else if (jenis_dokumen == "SP3")
                {
                    rdl = "sp3.rdl";
                }
                else if (jenis_dokumen == "Pertanggungjawaban Panjar Kerja")
                {
                    rdl = "pertanggungjawaban.rdl";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (jenis_dokumen == "SPD")
                {
                    rdl = "deklarasi_area.rdl";
                }
                else if (jenis_dokumen == "Panjar Dinas")
                {
                    rdl = "panjar_dinas_area.rdl";
                }
                else if (jenis_dokumen == "Pengajuan Panjar Kerja")
                {
                    rdl = "panjar_kerja_area.rdl";
                }
                else if (jenis_dokumen == "SP3")
                {
                    rdl = "sp3_area.rdl";
                }
                else if (jenis_dokumen == "Pertanggungjawaban Panjar Kerja")
                {
                    rdl = "pertanggungjawaban_area.rdl";
                }
            }
            Response.Redirect(MyClass.Site + "/_layouts/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/sites/tracking/Report/"+rdl+"&Source="+MyClass.Site+"/Report/Forms/AllItems.aspx&DefaultItemOpen=1&rp:nopek="+nopek+"&rp:id="+ID);
        }
    }
```

Comment: put a break point and see which line throw an error, PS : usually this kind of error caused by : u are trying to get an index from an array which does not have it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check your index and array size where exception occurs. You are obviously trying to get item on index that is negative or exceeds (number of items in array - 1).

Comment: this not an answer, put it in comment instead.